# How to remove blank lines only and retain the order

Tags: python, python-2.7

```
ShowOwi

g exsu n

Sierouz

nicee99
```

This is the output I get after performing ocr using tesseract.The blank space varies in occurence Some times there is multiple blanks between usernames sometimes none between the usernames.I am trying to find a solution which would strip these blank lines .I want to strip them before writing to the file.How to remove only the blank space but retain them one below other using python.

I went through similar questions in SO regarding this but nothing seems tow work for me.

Comment: Is this a single string with newlines in it, or a list of strings?

Comment: single strings .The text shown here is copied as it is from a text file.I wnat to clear the blank lines before writing to the text.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

What about simply filtering your lines:

```
lines = output.splitlines()
filtered = [line for line in lines if line.strip()]
```

The `if line.strip()` implictly check that `line.strip() != ""` (empty string is a falsy value).

Of course, this can also be done using the functional way:

```
filtered = filter(lambda line: line.strip(), lines)
```

And to get a single string back:

```
new_output = '\n'.join(filtered)
```

Comment: [u'Psyfreak.', u'W1 .000.000', u'ZuZhang.', u'Blinde'].I get the following output written into text file when I applied your first solution.What I want is that .Psyfreak in line below w1.000.000 below it Zuzhang and so forth

Comment: @SachinDivakar I think you missed the step to get a single string back. ;)

Comment: sorry 1 week into python forgive my ignorance I did not understand you there .I just wrote filtered variable into the file so which step are you referring to ?

Comment: @SachinDivakar No problem. `filtered` is a list of string. You do not want a list of strings, so you have to `.join()` them together in order to get a single string. This is: `new_output = '\n'.join(filtered)`. Then you can write `new_output` to your file.

Comment: so will the last line give me output one below other

Comment: @SachinDivakar Yes, it should. `'\n'.join(filtered)` is like `filtered[0] + "\n" + filtered[1] + "\n" + ...` Each filtered line will be displayed on a separate line, without blank.

Comment: @SachinDivakar But maybe you should use the RomanPerekhrest answer which looks simpler.

Answer (score 3):

Simply with `re.sub()` function:

```
import re

s = '''
ShowOwi

g exsu n

Sierouz


nicee99
'''

result = re.sub('\n+', '\n', s.strip())
print(result)
```

The output:

```
ShowOwi
g exsu n
Sierouz
nicee99
```